# SpringBoot: using one yml in another yml

Tags: yaml, spring-profiles

I have been asked to use application-local.yml for our local environment but not to include username and password in that yml instead I need to use a separate yml or txt file which can contain the credentials and then I want to use that file in my application-local.yml file.
I want to keep the credential in separate file so that I will mark it in gitignore.

I tried creating a separate yml file and then used **spring.proflies.include** to include the yml in my application-local.yml but it didn't work.